# maven rpm plugin needs full path to source location in multi module project

Tags: maven, plugins, rpm

I have a multi module maven project. I am calling the RPM plugin from the parent pom, but unlike the maven assembly plugin, I need to provide the full path to the sources I wish to package into the RPM specified directory.

For example the following location path will not work unless I specify the full path:

```
<sources>
  <source>
    <location>/src/main/config</location>
  </source>
</sources>
```

Regular expressions and wildcards do not work too.

Any suggestions please?

thanks

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://mojo.codehaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/source-params.html) of the source parameter says:

> If the path does **not** start with /, it is taken to be relative to the
>   project's base directory.

So it should work if you remove the leading `/` from the location parameter.

-- update --

I made a little test with this simple multi-module project:

```
rpm-test
|-- module1
|   |-- pom.xml
|   |-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   |-- config
|       |   |   |-- mod1-file1.conf
|       |   |   |-- mod1-file2.conf
|-- module2
|   |-- pom.xml
|   |-- src
|       |-- main
|       |   |-- config
|       |   |   |-- mod2-file1.conf
|       |   |   |-- mod2-file2.conf
|-- pom.xml
```

The configuration of the rpm-maven-plugin in the **parent POM** looks as follows:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1-alpha-1</version>
  <inherited>false</inherited>
  <configuration>
    <copyright>2012, Me</copyright>
    <group>mygroup</group>
    <mappings>
      <!-- Option 1: Use the base directory and includes -->
      <mapping>
        <directory>/usr/local</directory>
        <sources>
          <source>
            <location>${project.basedir}</location>
            <includes>
              <include>**/src/main/config/**</include>
            </includes>
          </source>
        </sources>
      </mapping>

      <!-- Option 2: List each module separatly -->
      <mapping>
        <directory>/tmp</directory>
        <sources>
          <source>
            <location>${project.basedir}/module1/src/main/config</location>
          </source>
          <source>
            <location>${project.basedir}/module2/src/main/config</location>
          </source>
        </sources>
      </mapping>
    </mappings>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>rpm</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

When I query the the content of the generated RPM with `rpm -qpl`, I get these results:

```
/tmp
/tmp/mod1-file1.conf
/tmp/mod1-file2.conf
/tmp/mod2-file1.conf
/tmp/mod2-file2.conf
/usr/local/module1/src/main/config/mod1-file1.conf
/usr/local/module1/src/main/config/mod1-file2.conf
/usr/local/module2/src/main/config/mod2-file1.conf
/usr/local/module2/src/main/config/mod2-file2.conf
```

Comment: yes you're correct, but the path is present in many sub modules. They all have config files placed under src/main/config and I need to access them all so that they get packaged into the conf RPM location. Since I'm running from the parent module, the basedir path does point to the sub module src/main/config directories.

Comment: The simplest solution for this is to use ${project.basedir}/src/main/config.

Comment: When the rpm plugin does only run in the parent module (did you configure `<inherited>false</inherited>`?) it might be an option to use `<includes>` in your configuration:
`<source><location>${project.basedir}</location><includes><include>**/src/main/config</include></includes></source>`

It would be great if you could post how exactly you configured the plugin.

Comment: hi stefan. Wild card do not work with the rpm plugin for a multi module project it seems.

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution that works on my machine. As @khmarbaise mentioned, the `${project.basedir}` property should do the trick. There are two options: The first is to use the basdir as location together with `<includes>` (wildcards are possible there). However, the RPM will reflect the whole folder structure of the files (e.g. `/usr/local/module1/src/main/config/...`. The second option is to define a `<source>` configuration for each submodule. The RPM will then contain the files directly in the `<directory>` folder.

Comment: Interesting. thanks Stefan. I've opted for a separate rpm-module with a maven assembly plugin to prepare the directory structure with the files for me in that sep modules target dir, and then reference that separate module target dir for all the sources...similar to your second suggestion. This way I dont touch the parent pom and let this separate module hold the eventual RPM artifact. But the RPM is a side effect with this approach but this is sufficient for us. thanks for you help.